# How to fix the overlapped nodes with long text, in TikZ. Concept maps

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, trees, mindmaps

I'd like to get helping from you.
I want to have paragraphs in the nodes of the concept map with Tikz, I mean, texts with multiple lines.
I have a problem with texts, the nodes are overlapped.
Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tikz}  
%  
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}  
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}  
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[edge from parent fork down,edge from parent/.style={black,thick,draw},every node/.style={rectangle,draw,rounded corners}]
\node at (0,0) {
\begin{tabular}{m{30mm}}
Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long\\
Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long\\
\end{tabular}
}
child {node {text}}
child {node {text}
child {node {\begin{tabular}{m{30mm}}
Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long\\
Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long\\
\end{tabular}}}
child {node {\begin{tabular}{m{30mm}}
Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long\\
Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long\\
\end{tabular}}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Check subsection 16.4.3 “Text Parameters: Alignment and Width for Multi-Line Text” of the [PGF manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), pp. 179ff.: `tabular`, `align` key (manual line-breaks), `text width` key (fixed-width an manual line-breaks).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks a lot, but I have a problem, the nodes are superposed. I'm looking for some solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The placement of tree nodes depends on

- the `level distance` key,
- the `sibling distance` key (both default: `15mm`),
- the `growth parent anchor` key, and
- the usual `anchor` key of the children.

The growth path depends on:
 - the placement of the nodes,
 - the `parent anchor` key, and
 - the `child anchor` key (both default: `center`).

The `child anchor` is not important because the last path operator of the chosen growth path is `-|`. It could be set to `north`.

The path is:

```
(\tikzparentnode\tikzparentanchor) -- +(0pt,-.5\tikzleveldistance)
                                   -|  (\tikzchildnode\tikzchildanchor)
```

## Step 1: Changing the `sibling distance`.

In this example we could set the anchors to `east` and `west` but this would work only for two nodes and prevents us to do something we later need.

Therefore the `sibling distance` is set manually.

## Step 2 and 3: Changing `growth parent anchor` and setting all children nodes to `anchor=north`

The `level distance` is set between the `growth parent anchor` and the usual `anchor` of the children.

Setting `growth parent anchor=south` and `anchor=north` will set the `level distance` from border to border, not form center to center.

## Step 3: Changing `parent anchor`

The growth path starts at `(<parent node>)` and goes to a point that is half the level distance below `(<parent node>)` and then goes “horizontalvertically” (`-|`) to `(<child node>)`.

For the *calculation* of that middle point the `.center` anchor of the `<parent node>` is used, but *the actual line* is connected to the border of `<parent node>` (which coincidentally is also the `.south` anchor)!
This is the reason that for big nodes (to be specific: nodes which half height is greater than half the level distance) the line goes inside of the node despite that a relative coordinate is used.

This is the reason the start node-anchor is set via the `parent anchor` key to `south`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    edge from parent fork down,
    edge from parent/.style={black,thick,draw},
    every node/.style={rectangle,draw,rounded corners},
    every child node/.style={anchor=north}, % due to lack of a 'growth child anchor' style
                                            % the .north anchor is selected manually
                                            % this affects the placement
    par node/.style={
        text width=#1,
        align=center,
    },
    par node/.default=30mm,
    parent anchor=south,
    growth parent anchor=south,
]

\node[par node] (p) at (0,0) {
        Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long\\
        Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long
    }
    child {node {text}}
    child {node {text}
        [sibling distance=40mm]
        child {node[par node] {
                Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long\\
                Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long
            }
        }
        child {node[par node] {
                Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long\\
                Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long Text very long
            }
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]