# How to make Tikz Node Content fit?

Tags: nodes, tikz-trees, fit

I'm trying to make a decision tree with Tikz, but the text in my nodes overlap. Does anyone know how to fix that? Thanks so much!

```
\begin{tikzpicture}  
    \node {{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.}}  
        child {  
            node {Yes}  
            child {   
            child {  
                    node {\begin{tabular}{c}  
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\ 
                consectetur adipisicing elit, \\  
                sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt \\  
                ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.  
                \end{tabular}}  
                    child {  
                node {No}  
                child { node {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}  
                    child { node {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}  
                    }  
                }  
            }  
                    child {  
                node {Yes}  
                child { node {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}  
                    child { node {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}  
                    }  
                }  
            }  
        }  
            }  
    }  
    ;  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here is a picture of my TeX:

[image]

Comment: Similar problem/solution: [How to fix the overlapped nodes with long text, in TikZ. Concept maps](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88475)

Comment: Also a duplicate of [drawing tree using tikz, child overlap](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60571).

Answer (score 5):

The powerful [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package ([manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/forest/forest.pdf), [forest](/questions/tagged/forest)) sets the sibling distance automatically so that nodes do not overlap.

By adding the option `for tree={grow=east,anchor=center}` to the `forest` environment (without the usual bracket `[ … ]`!):

```
\begin{forest} for tree={grow=east,anchor=center}
   [{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.}
      …
   ]
\end{forest}
```

we’ll get a horizontal layout (the `anchor=center` is needed for the multi-lined node).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.}
  [Yes
    [{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
     consectetur adipisicing elit, \\
     sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt \\
     ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.},align=center
      [No
        [Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
          [Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet]
        ]
      ]
      [Yes
        [Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
          [Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

### Output (growing north to south)

[image]

### Output II (growing west to east)

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to make it go from left to right instead up to down?

Comment: @Photosynthesis Take a look at the updated answer. Of course you might use more line-breaks in those long nodes.

Comment: If you leave a blank line like that, you won't get anything but an error .

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `text width=<length>` and/or `align=<value>` options to allow automatic text wrapping or manual line change commands; you can so that on a per-node basis:

```
\node[text width=3cm] {text};
```

or define a style for a group of nodes, or apply the style for all of the nodes using `every node/.style`.

Also, there's no need for the `tabular` environment; you can also use the `sibling distance=<length>` option if needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style={text width=3cm,align=center},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=4cm}
]
    \node {{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.}}  
        child {  
            node {Yes}  
            child {   
            child {  
                    node[text width=6cm] {  
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\ 
                consectetur adipisicing elit, \\  
                sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt \\  
                ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.  
                }  
                    child {  
                node {No}  
                child { node {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}  
                    child { node {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}  
                    }  
                }  
            }  
                    child {  
                node {Yes}  
                child { node {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}  
                    child { node {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}  
                    }  
                }  
            }  
        }  
            }  
    }  
    ;  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, that's super helpful! Question: is there a way to set sibling distance for each individual node? Right now, if I do multiple branches, one of them still overlaps: http://i.imgur.com/MzolYs4.jpg